# Странно работает document.getElementById для элементов в JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf

Есть jsf код:

```html
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript  name="test.js"/>
        <h:form id="form" styleClass="form" >
                <h:inputText id="R" class="R" value="#{point.r}"> </h:inputText>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

И есть код в  javascript  в отдельном файле :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("R"))
});
```

Но почему то document.getElementById возвращает все время null.
Почему?

Comment: Надо смотреть сгенерированную разметку `hrml`. Это можно сделать через DevTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При формировании `id` компонента для `HTML`-страницы, `JSF` к указанному `id` добавляет в качестве префикса `id` формы и идентификаторы всех компонентов-контейнеров (например, `JSF`-панелей). Выглядит примерно так: `"myFomId:myComponentId"`. Если `id` не указан явно, то он будет сгенерирован.

Изменить такое поведение можно указав атрибут `h:form prependId="false"`. Не рекомендую делать это без лишней надобности. Также не рекомендую использовать `JavaScript`, т.к. абсолютное большинство задач обычно можно решить на "чистом" `JSF`.

Comment: И как сделать рисование в canvas или вычисление логической функции на основе данных формы в JSF?

Comment: `JSF` - Java **Server** Faces, практически всё что связано с интерфейсом, проходит через сервер. Стандартный подход при этом - данные сабмитятся на сервер и там происходят все вычисления, там же можно выполнять и рисование и возвращать браузеру. Если логика Вашей ИС рассчитана на то, чтобы всё делать в браузере - вероятно, `JSF` - не Ваш выбор.